# what does : do when assigning flags in a command line argument?

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to add command line arguments to a program I am writing. I found a tutorial on-line however I'm not entirely sure what some of the lines actually do.The main bit I currently don't understand is what the : does when assigning the flags eg. `"hi:o:"`

Why are there 2 :'s around the o? but not the h or the i? Also, have I understood correctly that the first list `"hi:o:"` is the shorthand and that the second list `["ifile=","ofile="]`is the more verbose version?

```
try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
      sys.exit(2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` indicates that the preceding option takes an argument. That is, you call the program with something like `-i inputfile -o outputfile`.

Your intuition about the second list is correct.